# Need suggestions for fixing ABC error?

Tags: python-3.x, abc

I'm creating a boid flocking simulator and getting some errors. Suspecting they are issued by wrong usage of ABC. But I can't fix the error, been trying for a day.

the primary issue is in the Check_input class. flyers is somehow undefined and I'm trying to append them to the FlyerList if the input is registered.

Linked the whole code for full perspective.

```
from precode import Vector2D, intersect_rectangle_circle, intersect_circles
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from config import *
import pygame

class Flyer(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def draw(self):
      pass

  @abstractmethod
  def move(self):
      pass

class Boids(Flyer):
  def __init__(self):
     self.radius = 7
     self.pos = Vector2D(100,100)
     self.speed = Vector2D(1,1)
     pass

  def draw(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)), 
    self.radius)
       pass

  def move(self):
     self.pos += self.speed

    if self.pos.x + self.radius >= screen_res[0]:
        self.speed.x *=  -1
    if self.pos.x - self.radius <= 0:
        self.speed.x = self.speed.x  * -1
    if self.pos.y - self.radius >= 0:
        self.speed.y *= -1
    if self.pos.y + self.radius < screen_res[1]:
        self.speed.y *= -1
    pass

 class Hoiks(Flyer):
   def __init__(self):
    self.radius = 9
    self.pos = Vector2D(200,200)
    self.speed = Vector2D(8,8)


   def draw(self,screen):
      pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)), 
      self.radius)

        pass

    def move(self):
       self.pos += self.speed
       if self.pos.x + self.radius >= screen_res[0]:
          self.speed.x *=  -1
       if self.pos.x - self.radius <= 0:
          self.speed.x *= -1
       if self.pos.y - self.radius >= 0:
          self.speed.y *= -1
       if self.pos.y + self.radius < screen_res[1]:
          self.speed.y *= -1



 class FlyerList():
    flyers = []

    def move_all(self):
      for flyer in self.flyers:
         flyer.move()

    def draw_all(self):
      for flyer in self.flyers:
         flyer.draw()


 class Check_input():

    def boidspawn(self, event):
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         flyers.append(Boids)

    def hoikspawn(self, event):
       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            flyers.append(Hoiks)






 class Game:
   def __init__(self):
     pygame.init()
     self.flyer_list = FlyerList()
     self.check_input = Check_input()

   def Gameloop(self,event):
      while 1:
          self.flyer_list.move_all()
          self.flyer_list.draw_all()
          self.check_input.boidspawn(event)
          self.check_input.hoikspawn(event)
        #  self.check_collision()


 def game_code():

 #    pygame.init()

   game = Game()

   boid = Boids()
   hoik = Hoiks()
   bats = FlyerList
   check = Check_input()





  screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_res)
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and 
               event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               exit()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (0, 0, screen.get_width(), 
    screen.get_height()))
    time_passed = clock.tick(30) # limit to 30FPS 
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0   # convert to seconds

    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


    game.Gameloop(event)

    pygame.display.update()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
  game_code()
```

Comment: if you have traceback errors... poste them by editing your question and append to the bottom.

Comment: Taking a quick glance at the code, seems like you need to fully qualify `flyers` when using it within the `Check_input` class's functions by doing `FlyerList.flyers`, otherwise it thinks `flyers` is local to the function. Of course, I'm presuming that's the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: yeah you were right about FlyerList.flyers. No traceback error thus far, program just crashes upon execution. Will try some more and come back to you. thanks btw

Comment: Still keeps crashing,  Won't even load the screen. Can't seem to find the error. annoying